# ImportError: No module named... (basics?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, importerror

A very basic question that has been confusing me. Can't seem to find any solutions online so far...

I have a simple script and want to import another script I just made in the same directory.

What is the proper way of doing this?

I just tried combos of  import myfile, from myfolder import myfile, import myfolder.myfile, etc

I get ImportError: No module named 'myfile'

Cheers

Comment: This just means that Python cannot find a file called `myfile.py`.

Comment: please post your code, and your directory structure

Comment: does it not expect it to find it in the same place as the original file?

Comment: they're in the same directory at the moment. Tried putting the target import in a level below, made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your current directory isn't on the `PYTHON_PATH`, which is what `import` searches when you call it. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

If you want an immediate fix, you can use the following:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

This adds the directory containing the script's file to the python path.

This will only work if the directory these scripts are in is set up as a [package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: Ok, so there's no simpler way of doing it?

Comment: also, does that permanently add the directory to the python_path?

Comment: It adds the directory to the path for the scope of the import (so the lifetime of the script in this case). `sys.path` is a copy of the environment variable, not the actual environment variable, so that you can do things exactly like this.

And no, that's how the `import` command works. The package containing the module must be on `PYTHON_PATH`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Now I might be being a total noob but it's not recognising   < __file__>

Comment: Oh is this because I'm running the script through an editor instead of a command line

Comment: Depending on how you're hitting that line, `__file__` may or may not exist (for example if you run the module from the interactive interpreter).

Comment: Only just saw you're comment but that's right. Just got it working through a terminal (after cleaning up some env variables). Do you know the right approach to doing this through an interactive interpreter?

Comment: silly question, just put the directory in manually.

Comment: although that doesn't seem to work. In any case, problem is solved :)

Comment: You could try `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(''))`, should also give you the directory in the interactive case, **assuming** you launched python from that directory. It won't work in any other case though.