# Failed to import python file from the same directory (version 2.2)

Tags: python, cmd, wlst, python-2.2

I have the following python files:
help_functions.py
check.py
I'm trying to import help_functions file from check file (both files in the same directory) with the following command:

```
from help_functions import Utils
```

after running it from cmd with WLST which has Python 2.2 interpreter I get the following error:
`ImportError:no module named help_functions`

any idea what should I do to make it recognize the help_functions file?

Comment: I am having no problem importing them.

Comment: Importing fine in my machine. Cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: he probably is calling them from a different directory where you are calling them from within the directory, python checks for modules in your current working directory.
Probably need to add an __init__.py file in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: add the scripts containing folder (full path, not relative) to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Long answer: your scope is not what you think it is. See this answer for more details:
[ImportError: No module named... (basics?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275056/importerror-no-module-named-basics)